# Use email alisas for commit message in Bitbucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have a personal email address to log in to Bitbucket and I have an alias - my work email.

When I create a commit and push it into a remote repo the commit has my alias email as an author (done by .hgrc in a local repository). However, when I create a commit (or a merge) by web UI the author is my personal email.

So, I'm wondering, is it possible to use a specific email alias for a particular repository? In other words, I want to sign in with my personal email (or with a Google account) but use my work email for certain repositories.